# Redirect error while deploying nuxt app with aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

When I try to deploy the app the build completes without errors. When I go to the link provided (https://master.d3m2wky0hslwhr.amplifyapp.com/) I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS .

My build config:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: .nuxt
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Inside the app I have (index.vue, login.vue and register.vue)

I think it may be because im beeing redirected to url/index.html and that file does not exist in the proyect.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

Change -npm run build to -npm run generate
(This creates the index.html by default and converts everything to static)
Change baseDirectory to dist